# DAX formula to determine if a given date is a weekday or weekend day

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need some help with a DAX formula.

I work on a Power BI file that is linked to an Excel. In my Excel, I have a column with dates in the following format: "month/day/year"

I want to create a measure in Power BI that tells me if a given date is a weekday or a weekend day.

I have the following code that I found online:

```
Day Type = 
IF(WEEKDAY(dates[Date], 2) < 6, "Weekday", "Weekend")
```

However, when I want to use my table with dates in the WEEKDAY function of this code, I can't do it I don't know why. Am I doing something wrong?

Do you know a better code for that?

Last question, should I use a calculated column or a measure?

thank you very much!

Comment: What are your table name and the date column name?

Comment: My date column name is simple, it is just 'Date'. but I can't find it when I use the WEEKDAY function it's weird :/

Comment: What is your table name?

Comment: You mean the Excel table? If it is this one your talking about, the name is 'Table_for_Measures'

Comment: What I mean is the table name including the 'Date' column in Power BI.

Comment: I have one big table named 'Table_for_Measure', in this table I have several columns such as Date, WeekDay, Sales, etc.

Comment: Well, can you show a screenshot of the Power BI data fields?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250352/discussion-between-kevin-and-haseo1997).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to aggregate your date column, like COUNT(Date[date]), but you want to calculate the *Day Type* for every row, so that you can later filter on it.

This means you have to use a **calculated column** and not a **measure**. Try this out and you'll see that Power BI will also recognize your `Date[date]`column, because in a calculated column you have a **row context**, in measures you don't.

Comment: Thank you it is working. You were right, the problem was not the code but the fact that I was using a Measure instead of a calculated column!